# Least Square Apply Non-Linear Function

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I am study numerical methods and I see that question.

Considering that
$f(1)=0.6065, f(1.5)=0.8825, f(2)=1, f(2.5)=0.8825, f(3)=0.6065.$

Utilizing the method for least squares, approximate the function $f(x)$ with the function

$\mathfrak{P}(x)=e^\frac{-(a-x)^2}{b}$;

Where $a,b\in\mathbb{R} $are the parameters need determine.

I linearized $\mathfrak{P}(x)$ and I obtained that:

$ln(\mathfrak{P}(x))=\dfrac{-a^2+2ax-x^2}{b}$

but I stay confused about how to proceed  now.

How can I do that?

Comment: You are trying to minimize $\sum_{x \in \{1,1.5,2,2.5,3\}} \|p(x,a,b)-f(x)\|^2$, where $p$ is your function above.

Comment: Without linearized?

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do. Presumably you are to find $(a,b)$ that minimize the sum of squares error.

Comment: exercises my teacher passed for the test

Comment: Did you ever come to closure on this?

Comment: Will MATLAB code any help? Basically you are trying to solve Non Linear Model Fitting.